# Assigning Rails selection box data to a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have the following selection box, which lists all the companies in the database:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <% @companies.each do |company| %>
    <option>><%= company.name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

How do I assign the selected company to a variable named "selected_company" when I click submit? Can you give me an example of how the form and the controller would look like?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Check some tag helpers:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag

And some options helpers:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

The name that you set in tag is the param key on controller:

```
# View
<%= select_tag "company", options_from_collection_for_select(@companies, "id", "name") %>

# Controller
def some_action
  @selected_company = params[:company]
end
```

Comment: How is the action "some_action" being called from the form? Would you mind showing me how the form with the submit button looks like? Thank you again!

Comment: 'some_action' is the action in controller. Check more about forms in rails guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html and more about form_tag in api doc http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag